# Click on a btn without triggering div click not working as expected

Tags: javascript, reactjs

codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/currying-breeze-depdc9?file=/package.json

I have a Card component that has 4 potential states: "active", "selected", "discarded", "complete". Depending on the state, I need to display a different css class.

The states are set by clicking on specific parts of the card and each part is a "toggle" (one click sets it, another click "unsets" it):

- default state is active,
- if the user click anywhere on the card, it gets "selected" and two buttons appear inside the card ("back", "discard").
- if the user clicks on "back", I need to toggle the state bac to "active".
- if the user clicks on "discard" I need to set the state to "discarted"

The state is stored at the "App" level and I am passing it to the component through props. This means that for updating the states I am passing some "handler" from the app to the component (SelectCard, DiscardCard)

Here below is my code.

I am able to toggle the "active"-->"select"-->"active" through the function `SelectCard`.

However, I am doing something wrong since I can't manage to get the click on "discard" to actually call the `DiscardCard` function.

My feeling is that it has something to do with the fact that the btn is inside the div and I have an "onClic" for the div that calls `SelectCard` so when I click on the "discard btn" it's like I am clicking into the div as well and things don't work out.

But maybe it's something else. Not sure.

```
import { useState } from 'react'
import reactLogo from './assets/react.svg'
import Card from './components/Card'
import data from "./assets/data.json"
import {nanoid} from "nanoid"

function App() {
  const [people, setPeople] = useState(data['people'].map(
    el=>{
      return {
        ...el,
        'key' : nanoid(),
      }
    }
  ))

  const [myCard, setMyCard] = useState(
    {
      "name":"Name and Surname",
      "img":"https://i.picsum.photos/id/1070/200/300.jpg?hmac=dJNTYlLwT_0RupxbJNbw5Wj-q2cCTB4Xh-GqWRofIIc",
      "description": "This is a silly descriptionhis is a silly descriptionhis is a silly description",
      'key' : nanoid(),
      "selected":false,
      "active":true,
    }
  )


  function SelectCard(CardKey){
    console.log('SelectCard')
    setPeople(oldPeople=>{
      return oldPeople.map(el=>{

        return el.key === CardKey
                ? { ...el, 'state': el.state === 'active'?'selected': 'active'}
                : { ...el, 'state':'active'}
          })
    })
  }

  function DiscardCard(CardKey){
    console.log('DiscardCard')
    setPeople(oldPeople=>{
      return oldPeople.map(el=>{
        return el.key === CardKey
                ? { ...el, 'state': el.state === 'discarded'?'active': 'discarded'}
                : { ...el}
          })
    })
  }

  const cards = people.map(el=>{
    return <Card 
            key = {el.key} 
            item={el} 
            onPress={()=>SelectCard(el.key)}
            onDiscard={()=>DiscardCard(el.key)}
          />
  })

  
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className='container'>
        <div className='left'>
          <div className='cards'>
            {cards}
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className = 'right'>
          <h4>You are: </h4>
          <Card key = {myCard.key} item={myCard}/>
        </div>
     </div>
     
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

```
import { useState } from 'react'

function Card(props) {
  //const [count, setCount] = useState(0)

  function getClassName(state) {
    switch (state) {
      case "active":
        return "";
      case "selected":
        return "overlay-selected";
      case "discarded":
        return "overlay-discarded";
      case "complete":
        return "overlay-complete";
      default:
        return "";
    }
  }

  

  const className = `card ${getClassName(props.item.state)}`

  return (
    <div 
        className={className} 
        onClick={(event)=>{
            props.onPress()}}>
        <img className='card-img' alt='Card Image' src={props.item.img} />
        <h3 className='card-title'>{props.item.name} </h3>
        { props.item.state === 'selected' ? 
        
            <div className='card-cta'>
                <button 
                    className='btn btn-back'
                    onClick={ props.item.selected ?  (event)=>
                        { 
                            props.onPress
                            //event.stopPropagation()
                        }
                         : ()=>{}}
                >Back</button>
                <button 
                    className='btn btn-discard'
                    onClick={ 
                        (event) =>{
                            //event.stopPropagation()
                            props.onDiscard
                            }
                        }
                >Discard</button>
            </div>
        : 
        <p className='card-description'>{props.item.description} </p>  
    
        }
        
    </div>
  )
}

export default Card
```

Comment: Could you, please, wrap your code  in codesandbox and share with the link, I could try to fix it

Comment: Here it is: https://codesandbox.io/s/currying-breeze-depdc9?file=/package.json.  THanks for the help! I am actually getting another error now because of something I am trying to do (passing multiple functions through one prop as a dictionary. )

Comment: NeverMind, always the same problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For stopping the event from bubling up to other handlers, you need to call `stopPropagation` on the event.

Then, as mentioned in the other question, you need to actually run the handler you passed. And in order to call a handler in a block of code you need to add `()` after its name.

So for the Back you need

```
onClick={
  props.item.selected
    ? (e) => {
        e.stopPropagation();
        props.onPress();
      }
    : undefined
}
```

and for Discard you want

```
onClick={(e) => {
  e.stopPropagation();
  props.onDiscard();
}}
```

Demo at https://codesandbox.io/s/competent-swartz-d05x9y