# Passing a dictionary of functions but somehow failing to access it correctly

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an `App` component where I define two functions `A` and `B`.

I am then passing these two functions to a `Card` component as follow

```
          <Card 
            key = {el.key} 
            item={el} 
            onPress={{
                select : ()=>A(el.key),
                discard : ()=>B(el.key)
          }}
          />
```

however, for some reason, when inside my `Card` i do something like

```
    ....
    <div 
        className={className} 
        onClick={props.onPress.select}>
    </div>
    ...
```

I get this nasty error

```
react-dom.development.js:18687 The above error occurred in the <Card> component:

    at Card (http://localhost:5174/src/components/Card.jsx?t=1670102247232:33:48)
    at div
    at div
    at div
    at App (http://localhost:5174/src/App.jsx?t=1670102247232:24:31)

Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.
Visit https://reactjs.org/link/error-boundaries to learn more about error boundaries.
react-dom.development.js:26923 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'select')
    at Card (Card.jsx:28:32)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:16305:18)
    at mountIndeterminateComponent (react-dom.development.js:20074:13)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:21587:16)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:27426:14)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:26557:12)
    at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:26466:5)
    at renderRootSync (react-dom.development.js:26434:7)
    at recoverFromConcurrentError (react-dom.development.js:25850:20)
    at performConcurrentWorkOnRoot (react-dom.development.js:25750:22)
```

what am I doing wrong?

Here below both the App code and the Card code

```
import { useState } from 'react'
import reactLogo from './assets/react.svg'
import Card from './components/Card'
import data from "./assets/data.json"
import {nanoid} from "nanoid"

function App() {
  const [people, setPeople] = useState(data['people'].map(
    el=>{
      return {
        ...el,
        'key' : nanoid(),
      }
    }
  ))

  const [myCard, setMyCard] = useState(
    {
      "name":"Name and Surname",
      "img":"https://i.picsum.photos/id/1070/200/300.jpg?hmac=dJNTYlLwT_0RupxbJNbw5Wj-q2cCTB4Xh-GqWRofIIc",
      "description": "This is a silly descriptionhis is a silly descriptionhis is a silly description",
      'key' : nanoid(),
      "selected":false,
      "active":true,
    }
  )


  function SelectCard(CardKey){
    console.log('SelectCard')
    setPeople(oldPeople=>{
      return oldPeople.map(el=>{

        return el.key === CardKey
                ? { ...el, 'state': el.state === 'active'?'selected': 'active'}
                : { ...el, 'state':'active'}
          })
    })
  }

  function DiscardCard(CardKey){
    console.log('DiscardCard')
    setPeople(oldPeople=>{
      return oldPeople.map(el=>{
        return el.key === CardKey
                ? { ...el, 'state': el.state === 'discarded'?'active': 'discarded'}
                : { ...el}
          })
    })
  }

  const cards = people.map(el=>{
    return <Card 
            key = {el.key} 
            item={el} 
            onPress={{
                select : ()=>SelectCard(el.key),
                discard : ()=>DiscardCard(el.key)
          }}
          />
  })

  
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className='container'>
        <div className='left'>
          <div className='cards'>
            {cards}
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className = 'right'>
          <h4>You are: </h4>
          <Card key = {myCard.key} item={myCard}/>
        </div>
     </div>
     
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

and the card

```
import { useState } from 'react'

function Card(props) {
  //const [count, setCount] = useState(0)

  function getClassName(state) {
    switch (state) {
      case "active":
        return "";
      case "selected":
        return "overlay-selected";
      case "discarded":
        return "overlay-discarded";
      case "complete":
        return "overlay-complete";
      default:
        return "";
    }
  }



  const className = `card ${getClassName(props.item.state)}`

  return (
    <div 
        className={className} 
        onClick={props.onPress.select}>
        <img className='card-img' alt='Card Image' src={props.item.img} />
        <h3 className='card-title'>{props.item.name} </h3>
        { props.item.state === 'selected' ? 
        
            <div className='card-cta'>
                <button 
                    className='btn btn-back'
                    onClick={ props.item.selected ?  (event)=>
                        { 
                            props.onPress.select
                            //event.stopPropagation()
                        }
                         : ()=>{}}
                >Back</button>
                <button 
                    className='btn btn-discard'
                    onClick={ 
                        (event) =>{
                            //event.stopPropagation()
                            props.onPress.discard 
                            console.log('called me')
                            }
                        }
                >Discard</button>
            </div>
        : 
        <p className='card-description'>{props.item.description} </p>  
    
        }
        
    </div>
  )
}

export default Card
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens for the

```
<h4>You are: </h4>
<Card key={myCard.key} item={myCard} />
```

where you do not pass any `onPress` property.

So you need to either pass dummy methods for this case as well, or use the optional chaining operator [`?.`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining), like so `props.onPress?.select`

---

Additionally, you should actually call the methods from your buttons

so

```
(event) =>{
  //event.stopPropagation()
  props.onPress.discard
  console.log('called me')
}
```

should become

```
(event) =>{
  //event.stopPropagation()
  props.onPress.discard() // <-- added the () here
  console.log('called me')
}
```

Comment: Makes sense! Thanks a lot! Quick additional question, I am facing some sort of problem handling clicks between buttons and divs...basically I am trying to ensure that if I click on a button inside a div I do not also account for a click on the div...I added a question for that, if you have any suggestion would be amazing: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74670677/react-js-click-on-a-btn-without-triggering-div-click-not-working-as-expected